# O nome "arthur" não existe no contexto atual C#

Tags: c#

Estou fazendo um teste onde busco pegar as informações do Cliente pelo ClasseMenu.

Porém, estou com dificuldade de passar a informação até o Programa.

Classe Cliente

```
public class Cliente
{
    public string nome { get; internal set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string dataNascimento { get; set; }
    public string cpf { get; set; }
    public string rg { get; set; }
    public string endereco { get; set; }
    public string senha { get; set; }
}
```

Classe Menu

```
public class ClasseMenu
{
    public Cliente titular;
}
```

Programa

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ClasseMenu contaUm = new ClasseMenu();
        contaUm.titular = arthur;

        Console.WriteLine(contaUm.titular);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: No seu caso, arthur é uma variável. Você não tem tal variável declarada. Se você o que como texto, deverá englobá-lo com aspas duplas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeira coisa você poderia criar um constructor especializado para a classe `Cliente` e nesse constructor preenche-se os campos `nome`, `email`, `dataNascimento`, `cpf`,`rg`, `endereco` e `senha`. Depois sobrescrever o método [`Object.ToString()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2) para que a chamada do método  `Console.WriteLine(contaUm.titular.);` se torne adequada:

```
  public class Cliente
  {
    public string nome { get; internal set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string dataNascimento { get; set; }
    public string cpf { get; set; }
    public string rg { get; set; }
    public string endereco { get; set; }
    public string senha { get; set; }

    // Todos os campo, exceto nome, possuem um valor na falta para evitar digitação 
    //desnecessária num exemplo.
    public Cliente(string nome, string email = "", string dataNascimento = "",
                   string cpf = "", string rg = "", string endereco= "", string senha = "")
    {
        this.nome =nome;
        this.email = email;
        this.dataNascimento = dataNascimento;
        this.cpf = cpf;
        this.rg = rg;
        this.endereco = endereco;
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    // Sobrescrição do método Object.ToString()
    public override string ToString()
    {
       return = $"Titular: {nome}, email: {email}, Nascimento: {dataNascimento}, CPF: {cpf}, RG: {rg}, endereço: {endereco}, senha: {senha}"
    }
 }
```

Então toda vez que quiser criar um cliente invoque o constructor da classe `Cliente`.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Cria um cliente só com o campo nome preenchido
            ClasseMenu contaUm = new ClasseMenu();
            contaUm.titular = new Cliente("Arthur");

            //Se quiser criar um cliente com todos os campos preenchido.
            ClasseMenu contaDois = new ClasseMenu();
            contaDois.titular = new Cliente("Jandira", "jandira@hotmail.com", "21/08/1987", "956087565-23", "000.67.58.53", "Rua dos Coqueiros nº23", "987abc567" );
    
            Console.WriteLine(contaUm.titular.ToString());
   

            Console.WriteLine(contaDois.titular.ToString());


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Augusto!

Answer (score 5):

Me parece que você está tentando usar a palavra `arthur` como uma string. Bem, strings literais precisam ser circundadas com aspas duplas.

```
contaUm.titular = "arthur";
```

Mas isso não vai deixar seu código correto. Porque a propriedade (campo, neste caso) `titular` deve ser uma instância de `Cliente`.

Provavelmente, o que você quer fazer é:

```
var cliente = new Cliente();
cliente.nome = "arthur";

// ... definição das outras propriedades

contaUm.titular = cliente;
```

Comment: A variável `titular` não seria uma classe do tipo `Cliente`?

Comment: @gato É verdade, meu chapa.

Comment: Essa solução é boa, mas dai tira o propósito de eu querer buscar a informação do Cliente pelo ClasseMenu.

Answer (score -2):

Como o usuario acima falou, as string no C# tem que está dentro de (") aspas duplas para representar um conjuto com varios caracteres. Uma dica é utilizar get e setters no seus parametros para criar um encapsulamento de suas propriedades.

No caso os Get seria que sua propriedade ela retornará um valor, o definido um ou outro dependendo do caso.

E os Setters seria para introduzir um valor a sua variavel, colocando metodo { set; } o valor vai ser inserido direto na propriedade, mas esse conceito é usado para que você possa controlar como os valores serão inserido.

Usar encapsulamento é sempre uma boa opção para não deixar seu codigo vulneravel a modificações que possam afetar o funcionamento do mesmo.

```
public class ClasseMenu
{
    public Cliente titular {get;set;}
}
```

Assim você respeita um conceito muito importante na programação orientada a objetos. E claro você pode definir so um get ou setter.